# Ubuntu 13.10 Amd Radeon HD 4870 No Drivers or Fglrx tools

Tags: drivers, 13.10, ati, fglrx, gpu

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to 13.10. I have a AMD Radeon HD 4870 Graphics Card. On 12.04 I used AMD Proprietary drivers from their website and had no problems but since switching to 13.10 when I tried to install the Drivers it says that there are fglrx tools missing that need to be there for install. I tried using apt-get to install fglrx, and when the download finished I rebooted my PC and said that the graphics drivers were no good and I had to reinstall 13.10. So I can't just apt-get the fglrx drivers like I have done previously. Does anyone have a solution and does anyone else have this issue? I would like to have the Catalyst Control Centre but that comes with the proprietary drivers not with the radeon open source drivers. I also use a 32 bit system if that helps. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think that AMD is supporting the 2xxx,3xxx,and 4xxx cards anymore.  There are legacy drivers for them, but they do not work for the newer kernels after 12.04.  There is a work around for them but from what I read, it is a 50/50 chance of it working, and you probably have to rework it after system updates. It might break your system also, use at your own risk.   I think your best bet would be to use the open source drivers, unless you must have the Radeon drivers for your system, you could reinstall 12.04. Colin